# Equality of these two series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know these two series are equal, but I don't underestand how seires 2 is made from seires 1. Can anybody please explain to me how can I convert series 1 to series 2?

series #1
$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=0}^{x-1} 1\right)P(x)$$

series #2
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{x=j+1}^\infty P(x)$$

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summation extends over the "discrete region" in the $x-j$ plane that lies below the line $x=j$.

In the first case, the first index of the inner sum $j$ runs from $0$ to just below the line $j=x$ and thus, the inner sum terminates at $j=x-1$.  The second sum of the outer index $x$ runs from $0$ to $\infty$.

In the second case, the first index is $x$ and the sum is again below the lint $x=j$.  Therefore, the inner sum starts at $x=j+1$ and runs to $\infty$.  The outer sum begins at $j=0$ and runs to $\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f(m,n)=\begin{cases}1&m<n\\0&m\geq n\end{cases}$$

Then series #1 is:

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} f(j,x) P(x)$$

and series #2 is:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{x=0}^\infty f(j,x)P(x)$$